# PasswordChangeForm is never valid, error messages always present in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to implement password changing functionality in my Django 2.1.7 webapp. Even when I use a `GET` request for the change password page, these two errors are present in the template:

The two password fields didn't match.
Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again.

Additionally, when I `POST` data with the form, `form.is_valid()` always returns false, even though I can confirm that the error messages (the same ones listed above) are false.

The form page gives no error messages unless I manually put them in.

I've tried the solution [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html) and many similar ones. As far as I can tell, my logic is the same.

**View**

```
def change_password(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Keep the user logged in after they change their password.
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect("manager:profile")
        else:
            print("INVALID PASSWORD")
            print(form.error_messages)
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)

    args["form"] = form

    return render(request, "manager/change_password.html", args)
```

**Template**

```
<head>
    {% extends 'manager/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}
        Change Password: {{ user.username }}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

{% block body %}

{% if form.error_messages %}
    {% for error, error_message in form.error_messages.items %}
        <b>{{ error_message }}</b><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br>
    <button class="btn grey darken-3" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

How can I:
1. Get the password change feature to validate correctly?
2. Show ONLY valid error messages resulting from `POST`?

Comment: What is the result if you try to print(form.errors) after failing the form.is_valid()?

Comment: `INVALID PASSWORD` and
```{'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match.", 'password_incorrect': 'Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again.'}```

Comment: Well there you go, the passwords you submitted are incorrect.

Comment: I can confirm that's not the case. I used "q" and "q" for my new password. That should cause an error, but not because it's mismatched. Additionally, I'm using the password I logged in with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class view  PasswordChangeView. It designed to work with PasswordChangeForm.

In your form it might have something to do with:

```py
#  from PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):

 def clean_old_password(self):
        """
        Validate that the old_password field is correct.
        """
        old_password = self.cleaned_data["old_password"]
        if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_incorrect'],
                code='password_incorrect',
            )
        return old_password
```

maybe run this method manually before form.is_valid method???
Sorry, cant comment. Dont have enought points..